# FetchRows not working with FireMonkey StringGrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings, stringgrid

I have set the FetchRows of the UniQuery to 25.
In VCL application, it works fine with DBGrid.
It shows only 25 records. And when i reach the bottom of DBGrid, it auto load more records.

But when in Firemonkey apps, the FetchRows didn't work.
it always show all the records.

I'm using Delphi XE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the connection with a query TGrid, TListBox, TListView this property will not work. Avoid using Livebindings this case. Make the connection with them manually.